# Getting the Windows Drivers Directory

Tags: winapi, device-driver

Is there an official / proper method of getting Windows’ drivers directory or do you just concatenate `"\\Drivers"` to `GetSystemDirectory()`?

To be clear, I mean the `Drivers` directory that is in the system directory (eg `System32`). Yes, drivers can technically be anywhere, but is there an official way (eg a function) to get *this specific directory*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard-coded into the kernel, although drivers don't have to be loaded from there. Here's some bits taken from various parts of the I/O subsystem, which loads drivers:

```
#define SYSTEM32_DRIVERS_DIR        (L"\\System32\\drivers\\")

...

        pathLength = sizeof(L"\\SystemRoot\\System32\\Drivers\\") - sizeof(UNICODE_NULL);
        path = L"\\SystemRoot\\System32\\Drivers\\";
...
```

Comment: @SLaks: It comes from the Windows Research Kernel.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special folder for drivers.  The special folders are CSLIDs (see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494(VS.85).aspx.

If it was a special folder then you could use the SHGetSpecialFolderPath (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: > *“There is no special folder for drivers”*   So it’s just coincidence that most/all drivers are in `\Windows\System32\Drivers`?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I’m checking if there is an official function for getting a string with the path to where the drivers are stored in Windows. (I don’t see what’s so confusing.)

Comment: What are you *doing* with that information once you have the location of "the drivers directory"

Comment: The drivers directory is there by convention. Drivers can be loaded from 'anywhere' (not really, but ...), as the load path is part of their service registry key.

Comment: @Christopher, yes third-party drivers can load from anywhere, but Windows for one keeps its own drivers in there. Is there a way to get that specific directory or do you just append like you would for any other directory?